# jQuery created <a> link not triggering in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer, onclick

I am trying to use jQuery to create a some custom clickable menu, the final product works fine everywhere else except in IE8... When I click on the link, nothing happen. However, if i open the debugger, and refresh the onclick attribute, then it works fine afterward in IE. So it seems like IE, didn't "see" the onclick created by jQuery? Could that be possible?

Here is some sample code:

```
var props;
props['views'] = [ 'item1', 'item2', 'item3' ];
```

saving the onclick from another  link and transfer it to the menu

```
props['onclick'][i] = $(this).closest('a').attr('onclick');
```

then later on

```
for (var i in props.views) {
    var a = $('<a></a>');        

    // override the class from props.linkclass
    var cssclass = 'myMenu';
    // override the onclick from props.onclick[i]
    var onclick = props.onclick[i] + ';highlightDynamicMenu(this);';
    a.attr( {
        'class' : cssclass,
        'href' : 'javascript:void(0);',
        'onclick' : onclick }
    );
    a.append(props.views[i]); // name of the link

    menu.append(a);
}
```

This is the  link that gets generated from my code, again, works perfectly fine everywhere else except IE8... ugh.

```
<a onclick="javascript:showMyDiv('div1208', 'div1208', event);highlightDynamicMenu(this);" class="myMenu" href="javascript:void(0);">item1</a>
```

Now, as I was mentioning before, if I open the debugger, and refresh the link, say removing  "javascript:" and hit enter, then IE8 would "see" the link...

What exactly is the issue here? >.<

**Update:** I tried using: `a[0].setAttribute('onclick',onclick);` IE8 still won't pick it up...

Comment: why using attributes and not going directly with handlers ?

Comment: You've got jQuery at your disposal. Why are you doing everything the hard way?

Comment: Wait, what? I'm doing it the hard way? I am using jQuery.

Comment: FYI, you don't need the `javascript:` in the onclick.  You only need that in an `href`

Comment: I did trim out the `javascript:` previously, but that did not help in this situation. The `javascript:` is copied directly from where I saved the link, which is generated by someone else's code, that is why I try to keep it intact if possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not manipulate the `onclick` attribte in this way. Inline handlers are in general a bad idea, so hacking around with them like this is even worse.

Instead, you should use event handlers. In this case:

```
a.click(highlightDynamicMenu);
```

You can keep `attr... 'onclick':props.onclick[i]`, since it looks like you're passing a string, but really you should try to make that an anonymous function and pass it through.

Comment: I can't use click, because i am not just calling a single function, I also need to call the function that was saved in `props.onclick[i]`, PLUS, my `highlightDynamicMenu()`

Comment: Actually, I think the problem is the `event`, in the sub-function that i need to call `showMyDiv('div1208', 'div1208', event)`, I am unable to pass `event` over to that function if I use `a.click()`. Is there a way to carry the event over?

Comment: So the solution is to use `.click()`, however, I had to use a workaround to bypass the `event` passing issue, I end up passing `null` as `event`, good thing that the old function doesn't actually use `event` anymore... However, it would still be nice to know how @Kolink 's solution could work with passing in variable that way.

Answer (score 0):

No Issue in code by Defualt most of times IE behaves differently than others. 
Similar issue reported on msdn.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/iewebdevelopment/thread/ec196223-248b-4483-ada8-93838f5c5249/

Try like this
Assuming `props.onclick[i]` sarts with `javascritp:` as per your example `onclick="javascript:show('div1208', 'div1208', event);highlightDynamicMenu(this);"`

```
var onclick = props.onclick[i] + ';highlightDynamicMenu(this);';
    a.attr( {
        'class' : cssclass,
        'href' : onclick, // On Click variable value which will be something like javascript:show('div1208', 'div1208', event);highlightDynamicMenu(this);
         }
    );
    a.append(props.views[i]);
```

Comment: 'href' : 'onclick',  What does mean?